# Perl opening files from recursive directory

Tags: perl, recursion

So my program is supposed to recursively go through a directory and then for each file in the directory, open up the file and search for the words "error" "fail" and "failed."  Then it should write the instances where these words occur, as well as the rest of the characters on the line after those words, out to a file designated in the command prompt.  I have been having some trouble making sure the program performs the search on the files that are found in the directory.  Right now it does recurse through the directory and even creates a file to write out to, however, it does not seem to be searching through the files found in the recursing.  Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Find;


my $argument2 = $ARGV[0];
my $dir = "c:/program/Scripts/Directory1"; #directory to search through

open FILE, ">>$argument2" or die $!;   #file to write out 
my $unsuccessful = 0;
my @errors = ();
my @failures= ();
my @failures2 = ();
my @name = ();
my @file;
my $file;

my $filename;

opendir(DIR, $dir) or die $!;

while($file = readdir(DIR)){
next if($file =~ m/^\./);



foreach(0..$#file){
    print $_;
    open(FILELIST, '<', $_);    

    while(<FILELIST>){

    if (/Unsuccessful/i){
        $unsuccessful = 1;
    }
    if(/ERROR/ ){
        push(@errors, "ERROR in line $.\n");
        print  "\t\tERROR in line $.:$1\n" if (/Error\s+(.+)/);

    }
    if(/fail/i ){
        push(@failures, "ERROR in line $.\n");
        print FILE "ERROR in line $.:$1\n" if (/fail\s+(.+)/);

    }
    if(/failed/i ){
        push(@failures2, "ERROR in line $.\n");
        print FILE "ERROR in line $.:$1\n" if (/failed\s+(.+)/);

    }

    if ($unsuccessful){

    }

    }
    close FILELIST;


    }
}

closedir(DIR);
close FILE;
```

So, to clarify, my problem is that the search contained in the "while()" loop does not seem to be executing on the files found in the directory recursively.  Any comments/suggestions/help that you can give on why this may be happening would be very helpful.  I am new to Perl so some sample code would also just help me understand what you are trying to say.  Thank you very much.

Comment: How can this be searching recursively if it never calls opendir in a loop or recursively called function?

Comment: That could definitely explain my issues...Would you mind posting a sample loop that would make it recursive?

Comment: `egrep -RnI 'error|fail(ed)?' dir > file`

Comment: You import `File::Find`, but never use it. You call `for (0 .. $#file)` for an empty array... and even if the array was not empty, the `open` would fail because you try to open the array index, not the array element. Also, you would never notice this because you do not check the return value of the `open` statement, which is a Very Bad Thing to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, when I want to do something on recursive files, I start with find2perl . -print which generates the boilerplate for me with the `wanted` function from which I can modify to do whatever I want.

For example

```
# Traverse desired filesystems
File::Find::find({wanted => \&wanted}, '.');
exit;
sub wanted {
    return unless -f $File::Find::name;
    return unless -R $File::Find::name;
    open (F,"<",$File::Find::name) or warn("Error opening $File::Find::name : $!\n");

    while(<F>) {
        if(m/error/) { print; }
        if(m/fail/) { print; }
    }   
}
```

Comment: `readline() on closed filehandle F at script.pl line 6.` is the error you would get, because you did not check the return value of the `open` statement. If you had checked it, with `die $!`, you would get: `Permission denied`. You need to exclude directories, e.g. `next unless -f`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the constructive comments and help!

Comment: @TLP Thank you.  Added two guard clauses and the warn on the open.

Comment: Just tried this out and you have no idea how much it has helped - thak you again!

Comment: Just wondering - is there any way to alter this so that I can specify which directory it goes through?  Ie I can put in the path name for the directory?

Comment: @user1440061 Yes.  Thats the `'.'` in the File::Find::find() call.  This was generated with `find2perl . -print` to start it - specifying a directory other than '.' would generate different code.

Comment: Haha yes that does make sense.  I guess I just overlooked that.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a recursive perl directory listing. In reality, I would probably use file::find, or really just grep -R, but I am assuming this is homework of some kind:

```
use strict;

my $dir = $ARGV[0];
my $level = 0;

depthFirstDirectoryList($dir, $level);

sub depthFirstDirectoryList{
    my ($dir, $level) = @_;

    opendir (my $ind, $dir) or die "Can't open $dir for reading: $!\n";

    while(my $file = readdir($ind)){
        if(-d "$dir/$file" && $file ne "." && $file ne ".."){
            depthFirstDirectoryList("$dir/$file", $level + 1);
        }
        else{
            no warnings 'uninitialized';
            print "\t" x $level . "file: $dir/$file\n";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It's not for homework, more so me trying to combine programs I've written to see if I could get them to work together.  But thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Why the `no warnings`? Doesn't look like there could possibly be any such warnings there.

Comment: @tlp I had it as , instead of . in the printf and it was complaining when level is 0. I think now with . it is not needed

Comment: Comma or period does not matter.